# How to change the format of the date with datetime DateType in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following query that retrieves what I need from the database:

```
SELECT     
   dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.ID, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, 
   dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.employee.Name, 
   dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, 
   dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.Type, 
   ISNULL(dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.Status, '-') AS Status, 
   dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted
FROM 
   dbo.employee 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode 
INNER JOIN
   dbo.SafetySuggestionsType ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.TypeID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
   dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.StatusID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.ID
ORDER BY 
   dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted DESC
```

Instead of showing the date under `DateSubmitted` column as (`6/23/2012 7:15:00 AM`), I want to display it as `(Jun-2012)`.

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have above format using below example query :

```
  SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), CAST('6/23/2012 7:15:00 AM' AS DATETIME), 106), 8), ' ', '-') AS [Mon-YYYY]
```

In your query, you can try like this :

```
SELECT     dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.ID, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Title, dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Description, dbo.employee.Name, 
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username, dbo.Divisions.DivisionShortcut, dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.Type, ISNULL(dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.Status, '-') AS Status, 
                      REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted, 106), 8), ' ', '-') AS [Mon-YYYY]
FROM         dbo.employee INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog ON dbo.employee.Username = dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.Username INNER JOIN
                      dbo.Divisions ON dbo.employee.DivisionCode = dbo.Divisions.SapCode INNER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsType ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.TypeID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsType.ID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus ON dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.StatusID = dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus.ID
ORDER BY dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted DESC
```

Be sure,`dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted` column should be `datetime` type, otherwise cast it to `datetime` type

Comment: Why you are putting '6/23/2012 7:15:00 AM' in your query? The query should work for all the dates stored in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it. Also, Could you please explain to me the line that you added in the query?

Comment: Sorry for late reply...The query contains simple trick i.e. CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted, 106) returns the value in 'DD Mon YYYY' format which later extracted 8 character from right using "RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted, 106), 8)" statement which gives result as "Mon YYYY" i.e Jun 2012 so  at the last, the space in the result is replaced with '-' using " REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11),dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog.DateSubmitted, 106), 8), ' ', '-')" statement......

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative that is more self-explanatory:

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, GETDATE())) + '-' + RTRIM(YEAR(GETDATE()));
```

Used in your query (along with aliases, which will make your queries much easier for you and others to read):

```
SELECT 
  sl.ID, 
  sl.Title, 
  sl.[Description], 
  e.employee.Name, 
  sl.Username, 
  d.DivisionShortcut, 
  st.[Type], 
  ISNULL(ss.[Status], '-') AS [Status],
  sl.DateSubmitted,
  MonthSubmitted = CONVERT(CHAR(3), DATENAME(MONTH, sl.DateSubmitted)) 
    + '-' + RTRIM(YEAR(sl.DateSubmitted))
FROM 
  dbo.employee AS e
  INNER JOIN dbo.SafetySuggestionsLog AS sl
    ON e.Username = sl.Username 
  INNER JOIN dbo.Divisions AS d
    ON e.DivisionCode = d.SapCode 
  INNER JOIN dbo.SafetySuggestionsType AS st
    ON sl.TypeID = st.ID 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.SafetySuggestionsStatus AS ss 
    ON sl.StatusID = ss.ID
ORDER BY 
  sl.DateSubmitted DESC;
```

In SQL Server 2012, this will be much easier with the new [`FORMAT()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function, which has rough parity with the [C# format function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx), supports optional culture, and doesn't require having to memorize style numbers:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'MMM-yyyy');
```